# How to get store level contact email?

Tags: email, configuration, magento-1, transactional-mail

This code:

`Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')`

gets the value of the general contact email from "Default Config", but I have **several countries, each of them has different emails and I want to get them**. How can I do that ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the store ID as a second parameter.

Example for Store with ID 2:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', 2);
```

Comment: I didn't know that :) thx